# Не удаётся подключить Dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll

К проекту на C# подключаю библиотеку C++, библиотека полностью рабочая.
Руководство по подключению взял [тут](https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/combine-gui-of-c-with-c-codes/).

```
[DllImport("C:\\Users\\Zaki\\Desktop\\SetsGen.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern string GetSets(string ids, int power);

public void DllSub(string param)
{
   try
   {
      string myAns = GetSets(param, 3);
      string[] tokens = myAns.Split('/');
      foreach (var token in tokens)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(token);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Нативная сигнатура функции GetSets в Dll выглядит следующим образом:

```
std::string GetSets(std::string ids, int power)
```

Получаю исключение при обращении к портированной функции GetSets:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Test.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Какие могут быть причины и как исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Причины могут быть разные:

1. Ошибка в реализации нативной функции. Чтобы её исключить, попробуйте сделать пустую `GetSets` и пересобрать DLL.
2. Проблемы совместимости DLL и С# кода. Был случай, когда DLL, собранная в *C++Builder* приводила к ошибкам на стадии выполнения. Пересборка компилятором MS решила проблему на корню.
3. Неправильно передаются аргументы в функцию. См. [маршалинг](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx) строк.

Если сигнатура нативной функции содержит сложные типы из стандартной библиотеки C++ (в том числе и `std::string`), использовать такую функцию в P/Invoke будет проблематично (читай как невозможно). Разные компиляторы по-разному реализуют стандартные классы, поэтому передавать между модулями такие типы довольно опасно.

В данном случае наиболее правильное решение будет заключаться в том, чтобы экспортировать функцию, принимающую `const char*` (си-строку), а дальше в потрохах DLL уже можно использовать и `std::string` для удобства.

Comment: Проверил пункт 1: та же ошибка;
Проверил пункт 2: даже с разными настройками Debug/Release x86/x64 та же ошибка;
Не знаю как разобраться с 3-ей причиной?

Comment: @zakihatfild без изменения сигнатуры функции ничего не получится. `std::string` хоть и `std`, но `P/Invoke` такое не позволяет проворачивать.

Comment: а C# компилятор не будет ругаться, если в импорте функции из dll я пропишу сигнатуру с параметром const char* ?

Comment: @zakihatfild `string` в `c#` коде соответствует `const char*` в `c++`. По-крайней мере в моём коде такое работает без нареканий. Есть ещё [вопрос на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799685/how-to-pass-strings-from-c-sharp-to-c-and-from-c-to-c-using-dllimport), может пригодится.

Comment: @alexolut, Вы не правы. Тип `string` из `C`# имеет кодировку `Unicode` и соответствует типу `wchar_t` (`std::wstring`). Другое дело - тип, используемый при маршаллинге. Гляньте первый линк из моего ответа.

Comment: @Alexis если явно не изменять `CharSet` в `DllImport`, то `string` проецируется на `const char*`.

Comment: @alexolut, все верно, потому что если явно не задать `CharSet` в маршаллинге - используется `ASCII`, причем загадка, почему разработчики `.NET` сделали именно `ASCII` по умолчанию, ведь `C#` базируется на `Unicode`.

Comment: @Alexis сделали скорее всего по причине того, что в си нет `wchar_t`.

Comment: @alexolut, вполне возможно, хотя я считаю это в корне неверным, даже с выходом свежих фреймворков - они не изменили поведение.

Comment: @Alexis опасно менять поведение радикально. Может же куча старого кода сломаться, а это пострашнее каких-то мелких ништяков.

Comment: @alexolut, к сожалению это так, ничего не поделать. Но только данное поведение вносит сильную путаницу в маршаллинг и порождает множество вопросов на профильных ресурсах. Да и вообще сам маршаллинг - ахилесова пята дотнета, слишком криво и медленно он работает. Причем нет разницы между P\Invoke и C++ CLI в плане производительности маршаллинга.

Answer (score 2):

Проблем тут несколько, одна из которых — возвращаемое значение из нативной функции (`std::string`). В двух словах — стандартными методами вам не вернуть строку из нативного метода результатом.

Вторая проблема — строки в C# имеют кодировку Unicode, а нативная `std::string` имеет кодировку ASCII. Советую использовать `std::wstring` в нативном методе, `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` в маршаллинге и возвращать результат как показано тут:

- «[Return a std::wstring from C++ into C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051097/return-a-stdwstring-from-c-into-c-sharp)»,
- «[Passing strings from C# to C++ dll and back — minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20752021)».

**P. S.** С C++ CLI все намного лучше в плане маршаллинга.